# Does sql compact support multiple schemas?

Tags: sql-server-ce

In SQL2008, you can group tables into different schema, such as group all the lookup tables into lookup schema. Does this feature also supported in SQL Compact 4.0? I have tried to find some reference on this and hopefully can get some help from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, SQL Server Compact does not support multiple schemas, you can however use several database files within the same application.